# css alignment no property

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I was trying to use bootstrap in my react.js application, so here is what I'm trying to do:

```
<ListGroup.Item>
      {"Ass ".concat(pend.userName)}
      <div className="myDiv">
            <Button variant="success">
                  Add
            </Button>
...
```

Reason behind adding those button are simple, I just want some more productivity of that list.
And to create a better appeal I added a css named myDiv, defined like this:

```
.myDiv{
  margin-right:5%;
  alignment: right;
}
```

So when I render it I get output like this :

[image]

But I want them in the right side.

How can I get that look ?

react-bootstrap version - `^1.0.0-beta.16`

Comment: try to add `margin-left: auto;`

Comment: @demkovych margin-left: auto didn't worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use flexbox

```
.myDiv {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

or simple add `margin-left: auto;` to your div.

Answer (score 0):

```
div.myDiv {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is almost always the answer to css-alignment related questions.